# Django: updating model through form fails because of unique constraint

Tags: python, django, forms, unique-constraint

I am trying to update a model through a form while passing an instance of the model.

```
form = forms.ProfileForm(params, instance=profile)
if not form.is_valid():
    print form.errors
```

But it fails with:

"Profile with this App and Email already exists."

Here is the **params**:

```
params = {'first_name': u'foo', 'last_name': u'bar', 'app': 1, u'id': 12349, 'phone': u'999', 'email': u'foo@bar.com'}
```

The **model**:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=12349)
model_to_dict(profile)

{'first_name': u'foo', 'last_name': u'bar', 'app': 1, u'id': 12349, 'phone': u'12345', 'email': u'foo@bar.com'}
```

**model.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    app = models.ForeignKey('core.App', null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default=None, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default=None, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('app', 'email'),)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Profile
```

Django executes a function called *validate_unique* on the form while calling is_valid(). 
But why? It makes sense on insert but not on update.

I can work around while doing this before calling is_valid():

```
def f(): pass
form.validate_unique = f
```

Is there a proper solution?

Comment: We need the view, I guess django is trying to insert, not to update

Comment: So in case Django guesses an INSERT it checks the unique constraint? In case of an UPDATE is does not, is that correct? It fails on is_valid() not on save(). I can't post the view, its too complex but everything needed is shown in my post. I can reproduce the error in the shell without a view.